# Two apparently equal Python Unicode UTF8-encoded strings don't match

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

```
>>> str1 = unicode('María','utf8')
>>> str2 = u'María'.encode('utf8')
>>> str1 == str2
False
```

How is that possible?

Just in case it is relevant, I'm using the iPython Notebook.

Comment: I don't know if this should be an answer or not, but printing the representation of both strings I get: `u'Mar\xeda'` / `'Mar\xc3\xada'`, so there is a difference in it representation wise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a *unicode* string and a *byte* string. They are not the same thing.

One holds a Unicode value, `María`. The other holds a UTF-8 encoded series of bytes, `'Mar\xc3\xada'`.

Python 2 does do an implicit conversion when comparing Unicode and byte string values, but you should not count on that conversion, and it depends entirely on the default codec set for your system.

If you don't yet know what Unicode really is, or why UTF-8 is not the same thing, or want to know anything else about encodings, see:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score 3):

A string *cannot* be [both "Unicode" and "UTF-8 encoded"](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html); they are mutually exclusive. Hence, different strings.