# Concatenating Unicode with string: print '£' + '1' works, but print '£' + u'1' throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, unicode, string-concatenation

I've observed the following:

```
>>> print '£' + '1'
£1
>>> print '£' + u'1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print u'£' + u'1'
£1
>>> print u'£' + '1'
£1
```

Why does `'£' + '1'` work but `'£' + u'1'` doesn't work?

I looked at the types:

```
>>> type('£' + '1')
<type 'str'>
>>> type('£' + u'1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> type(u'£' + u'1')
<type 'unicode'>
```

This also confuses me. If `'£' + '1'` is a `str` and not a `unicode`, why does it print properly on my terminal? Shouldn't it print something like `'\xc2\xa31'?`

To add to the mix, I've also observed the following:

```
>>> u'£' + '1'
u'\xa31'
>>> type('1')
<type 'str'>
>>> type(u'£')
<type 'unicode'>
>>> print u'£' + '1'
£1
```

Why does `u'£' + '1'` not print out the `£` symbol properly, whereas `print u'£' + '1'` does? Is it because `repr` is used in the former, whereas `str` is used in the latter?

Also, how come concatenation of a `unicode` and a `str` work in this case, but not in the `'£' + u'1'` case?

Comment: Afaik you can only concat strings of the same type, i.e. `u'£'+u'1'` or `'£'+'1'`. You cannot mix them.

Comment: You are trying to decode as ascii with `print '£' + u'1'`, you are never going to see `'\xc2\xa31'` when you print unless you print the `repr` of the object, `print '£' + '1'` works because your shell is configured to accept utf-8

Comment: @Bjorn You can, I've done it many times, see the updated question

Comment: Boy, you are really hitting all the duplicates. I should just have closed this as one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry about that, could you point me to them?

Comment: @texasflood: a search through my `unicode` answers turns up [Python ascii utf unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27256006), [Python str vs unicode types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18034272) and [How are these strings represented internally in Python interpreter ? I don't understand](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14839028),  [Two apparently equal Python Unicode UTF8-encoded strings don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17343307),

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are mixing *object types*.

`'£'` is a bytestring, containing encoded data. That those bytes happen to represent a pound sign in your terminal or console is neither here nor there, it could just as much have been a pixel in an image. You terminal or console is configured to produce and accept UTF-8 data instead, so the *actual* content of that bytestring is the *two* bytes C2 and A3, when expresed in hexadecimal.

`u'1'` on the other hand is a *Unicode string*. It is unambiguously text data. If you want to concatenate other data to it, it too should be Unicode. Python 2 then will automatically decode `str` bytes to Unicode using the default ASCII codec if you try to do this.

However, the `'£'` bytestring is not decodable as ASCII. It *can* be decoded as UTF-8; decode the bytes explicitly, since we know the correct codec here:

```
print '£'.decode('utf8') + u'1'
```

When writing bytes to the terminal or console, it is your *terminal or console* that interprets the bytes and makes sense of them. If you write a `unicode` object to the terminal, the `sys.stdout` object takes care of encoding, converting the text to bytes your terminal or console will understand.

The same applies to taking input; the `sys.stdin` stream produces bytes, which Python can decode transparently when you use the `u'£'` syntax to create a Unicode object. You type the character on your keyboard, it is translated to UTF-8 bytes by the terminal or console, and written to Python to interpret.

That writing `'\xc2\xa3'` with `print` works, then, is a happy coincidence. You could take the `unicode` object, encode it to a *different* codec, and end up with garbage output:

```
>>> print u'£1'.encode('latin-1')
?1
```

My Mac terminal converted the data written for the `£` sign to a `?`, because the A3 byte (the Latin-1 codepoint for the pound sign) doesn't map to anything when interpreted as UTF-8.

Python determines the terminal or console codec from the [`locale.getpreferredencoding()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding), you can observe what your terminal or console communicated it uses via the `sys.stdout.encoding` and `sys.stdin.encoding` attributes:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Last but not least, you should not confuse *printing* with the representations echoed by the interpreter in interactive mode. The interpreter shows the outcome of expressions using the `repr()` function, a debugging tool that tries to produce Python literal notation wherever possible, using *only* ASCII characters. For Unicode values, that means any *non-printable, non-ASCII character* is reflected using escape sequences. This makes the value suitable for copying and pasting without requiring more than an ASCII-capable medium.

The `repr()` result of a `str` uses `\n` for newlines, for example, and `\xhh` hex escapes for bytes without dedicated escape sequences, outside the printable range. In addition, for `unicode` objects, codepoints outside the Latin-1 range are represented with `\uhhhh` and `\Uhhhhhhhh` escape sequences depending on wether or not they are part of the basic multilingual plane:

```
>>> u'''\
... A multiline string to show newlines
... can contain £ latin characters
... or emoji !
... '''
u'A multiline string to show newlines\ncan contain \xa3 latin characters\nor emoji \U0001f4a9!\n'
>>> print _
A multiline string to show newlines
can contain £ latin characters
or emoji !
```

Comment: OK thank you. So `u'£' + '1'` works because the `'1'` can be decoded as UTF-8?

Comment: But then `u'£' + '1'` returns a unicode object, so how does it combine the ASCII and UTF-8 objects? I would have thought that it would turn `'1'` into its UTF-8 equivalent, then concatenated two UTF-8 objects, which is trivial

Comment: There is no UTF-8 object. You have a *Unicode* object. UTF-8 is a codec, a way to encode Unicode codepoints to bytes, it is not the same thing as the Unicode data itself, just like using ISO 8601 notation to write down a date and a time is not the same thing as the timestamp itself.

Comment: @texasflood: That Python had to decode from UTF-8 to produce the `unicode` object is neither here nor there. The `'1'` is implicitly decoded from ASCII because you tried to concatenate it with a `unicode` object.